# Add an Image on top of another image

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet

The UI of my page currently shows an Image in backgroud and text on left hand top corner of the page. Following is the code I am using for the image.

```
<div>
    <div style= "z-index: 1; position: absolute; text-align: left; border: 1px solid black;">
        <img src="slide1.jpg" alt="alt text" style="height:220px;width:500px;border-width:0px;" />
    </div>
    <div id="curtain" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; padding-left: 10px;">
        <div style="background-color: transparent; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.8em; padding-top: 5px;">
            Profile
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 1em; width: 215px; color: #cccccc;">
           He is a good citizen and a great teacher.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add 2 small icons aligned vertically on the right hand side of this image.

Can someone help me with the css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/7KTEQ/

Just add `<div id="smallImages"><img src='ONE' /> <img src='two' /></div>` inside second div
and css for it is:

```
   #smallImages {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:400px;
}​
```

change margin-left for css depending on second div width and image sizes..